# not able to see workbook from ipad mobile app

Tags: ios, ipad, localhost, tableau-api

I had installed tableau server and tableau desktop in my pc. I created a workbook in tableau desktop and published in tableau server. Now i am able to see my workbook from tableau server & browser also. But i am not able to to see it from my ipad tableau mobile app or from ipad browser also because "localhost:8080" is the domain name. My question is  why the url is not coming like **xx.xxx.xx.xx:yyyy**  this. I guess if it is coming like this, then i am able to access it from my ipad app. Is my understanding right? Do i need to set any other configurations in tableau server. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to check is whether it is possible to view the Tableau Server site using `http://SERVERHOSTNAME:8080` on your PC, then to confirm that port 8080 is open to external access.

Once that is done, it should be possible to connect to your Tableau Server from your iPad (using the Tableau mobile app, or Safari) using that same URL.